# Change Owner in Linux

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I have got directory and its name matlab_temp. This directory's owner is root. I want to change directory's owner but I didn' succeed. I receive "chown: changing ownership of 'matlab_temp/'": Read-only file system" message. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: try remounting the partition in rw mode. Should be something like this: sudo mount -o rw, remount /<partition or device>

Comment: I don't pass rw mode.

Comment: what is the FS of your device?

Comment: My device's FS is ext4.

Comment: I didn't say in my question but my problem was about .iso file. I mounted .iso file with terminal command and mounted iso file was read-only. Then I used Furious ISO Mount program and I mounted iso file with this program. Then read-only problem removed. As a result I solved my problem. Thanks.